# How to update the password of user in azure ad using graph api

Tags: azure, api, graph, passwords, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft `graph` API to update the password of the user. I have below json request:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "userPrincipalName": "testuser34@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
        "password": "<new_password>"
    }
}
```

I am calling this `url` `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/testuser34@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com` using `PATCH` method. I am also passing the bearer token as Authorization header but getting below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "12781f2a-0cdd-449d-94d7-aae1440a7559",
      "date": "2020-04-03T02:52:57"
    }
  }
}
```

Error says `Insufficient privileges`. As per this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I am following, it says:

`When updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.`

I have checked this in app created, and this permission is there in the app registrations

[image]

But I am still getting this error. Can anyone please help on resolving this error. Thanks

Edit: Added the permission in Microsoft as well but still getting the same error

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I have below code  from which I am getting the token:

```
data = {    
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_secret": <client_secret>,
            "client_id": <client_id>,
            "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
       }

r = requests.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennant_id>/oauth2/token", data)

if r.status_code == 200:
    ret_body = r.json()
    token = ret_body['access_token']
else:
    log.error("Unable to get token from oauth {}, {}".format(r.status_code, r.json()))
```

**Edit3:**

I have also added the app name in user administrator:

[image]

But still the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Microsoft Graph`, so you need to add the permission in `Microsoft Graph` instead of `Azure Active Directory Graph`.
[image]

**Update:**

What you are using is the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), when using this flow, the `Application permission` is needed, if you want to get the token to update `passwordProfile`, the *Delegated permission* `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is needed, to update user with `Application permission`, we could just add `Directory.ReadWrite.All` at most, but this permission could not `reset user passwords`.

Check the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) from least to most privileged:

[image]

Then see the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-4) for `Directory.ReadWrite.All`:

[image: Directory.ReadWrite.All]

*Solution:*

To use client credentials flow to update `passwordProfile`, add the service principal of your AD App as a directory role in Azure AD.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> `User administrator` -> `Add assignments` -> search for the name of your AD App -> `Add`.

Then get the token to call the API, it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have added that as well but I am still getting this error

Comment: @SAndrew How did you get the token?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look at edit2. Thank you

Comment: I have checked all the permission and only `user.ManageIdentites.All` was missing. I have asked my IT person to add this and then I will test and update here. Thanks

Comment: You can assign User administrator role etc. to the app. That should allow password resets through client credentials flow. You can do that through the Roles and administrators tab.

Comment: @juunas Thank you for your reminder, I actually forgot this, added it to the reply.:-)

Comment: @SAndrew To use the client credentials flow to update the password, please see the update.

Comment: @JoyWang Inside user adminstrator, and in add asignment, I am only getting the list of users added in azure ad and not getting the name of the ad app. ?

Comment: @JoyWang When I searched with the name, it showed and I have added the ad name

Comment: @SAndrew It should work, follow the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTDuy.png.

Comment: @JoyWang I have done everything as per your instructions. Please have a look at edit 3.  Do I also need to add user administrator as app permissions. ?

Comment: @SAndrew It should work currently, it may need a while to take effect.

Comment: @JoyWang Okay will try it after 15-20mins.

Comment: @SAndrew Did you add it in the correct tenant which has the `tennant_id` in your request?

Comment: @JoyWang Now it is showing `Property userPrincipalName is invalid`